# How to get Transaction Receipt Event Logs?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I need to get the events emitted by my smart contract and consume them in the front end via web3.

I made some event on my contract that returns event winner and ticket number:

```
event Winner(uint256 ticketNumber, address winner);
```

So I emit this event, and I see it on transaction logs.

From Etherscan:

[image]

OK! What I need is the data: ticketNumber: 1, winner: 0x........
How did I get this from web3?

Im trying to use:

```
 await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txnHash, function (error, result) {
          console.log(result);
        });
```

But when I check console log, I cannot see this information, I suspect that result.logs.data is the right info, but I don't know for sure, and I don't know how to translate:

"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000005964b608ea267bfe9ef77707fce8105a2d145e7a"

Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents), there is `getPastEvents` method.

```
myContract.getPastEvents('MyEvent', {
    filter: {myIndexedParam: [20,23], myOtherIndexedParam: '0x123456789...'}, // Using an array means OR: e.g. 20 or 23
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
}, function(error, events){ console.log(events); })
.then(function(events){
    console.log(events) // same results as the optional callback above
});
```

you can also create event listeners:

```
contract.events.Winner()
.on('data', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
})
.on('error', console.error);
```

Docs about [subscription to events](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have the contract ABI with you, you can follow these steps to retrieve the events,
Step 1 - use `await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash)` as shown [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.5/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt).
Step 2 - You would receive an object with a field `logs`. This would be an array of objects with the length equal to the number of events emitted in that transaction. 
Step 3 -  In each of these objects there would be two fields that would be important to us. `data` and `topic`. The `data` field will contain all the unindexed parameters of the given event. To decode that you can use `web3.eth.abi.decodeLog(inputs, hexString, topics)` as shown [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.5/web3-eth-abi.html).
Step 4 - You can get the name of the event from the first element of the field `topic`. The first element here corresponds to the keccak256 of the event signature. `web3.utils.sha3(string)` can be used to to hash your event signature to check if the first entry of `topics` array match. More info [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.5/web3-utils.html#sha3).
Step 5-  If your event has indexed parameters, they can be found from the rest of the entries of the the `topics` array. To convert then to human readable form, follow the same steps as step 3.