# Can't get web3.js events

Tags: javascript, events, ethereum, web3js

I'm trying to get events from my smart contract with web3.js using either .once or .event.EventName calls but I never get any event.

```
contract = new w3.eth.Contract(contract_abi, contract_address);
await contract.events
.DrawCreated({})
.on('data', (error: any, event: any) => {
    console.log('Got events DrawCreated : %o', event);
    console.log('Got error : %o', error);
    handle_name();
});
```

Or:

```
contract = new w3.eth.Contract(contract_abi, contract_address);
await contract.once('DrawCreated', {}, (error: any, event: any) => {
    console.log('Got once DrawCreated : %o', event);
    console.log('Got error : %o', error);
    handle_name();
});
```

where handle_name is a simple function just doing some logging for now, but I do not get the event console.logs anyway:

```
handleNewDraw = (from: string, drawid: number) => {
    console.log(
      'LOTTERYFORM NEWDRAW event from ComponentDidMount'
    );
};
```

My ABI used to instantiate the contract does contain the events.

Any idea what I could miss? Are some options mandatory in those calls?

I read somewhere that event may only work with websocket RPC endpoints and not https : is that true? How could that be since default once are often https in wallets?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Transaction Receipt Event Logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367683/how-to-get-transaction-receipt-event-logs)

Comment: Thanks, but not really, this is useful for getting past logs, I want to listen and catch new events and react accordingly.